# ¿Cómo guardar configuracion de página?

Tags: php, css, html5, base-de-datos

Necesito guardar la configuración o preferencias de usuario de una página web, algo así como lo haciamos en sistemas de escritorio con el '.ini' o en el registro de windows. Debería guardar parametros como; estilo y otros predeterminados, que se guardarían en el pc donde se ejecute la página o podría ser, también, por usuario.

¿Cuáles serían las opciones?

Comment: Que has intentado? Tienes algún error?

Comment: `LocalStorage` con javascript, si lo que quieres es preferencias locales, ahora bien si quiere que esas preferencias persistan en otro computador pues debes almacenarlas en tu base de datos.

Comment: #DjCrazy $_SESSION y cookies pero los valores se pierden cuando se destruyen o caducan...

Comment: depende que quieras guardar y donde, si quieres guardar en php lo que dice @JuanCarlos te servira, pero si quieres guardar datos en el cliente la respuesta de kleith te ayudara.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se puede de diferentes maneras, siempre del lado del cliente, que sería desde `javascript`:

- `localStorage`
- `cookies`
- `sessionStorage`

## Definiciones

### `localStorage`

> El almacenamiento web puede verse de manera simplista como una mejora
>   de las cookies, lo que proporciona una capacidad de almacenamiento
>   mucho mayor. El tamaño disponible es de 5 MB, que es mucho más espacio
>   para trabajar que una cookie típica de 4 KB. Los datos no se envían de
>   nuevo al servidor para cada solicitud HTTP (HTML, imágenes,
>   JavaScript, CSS, etc.), lo que reduce la cantidad de tráfico entre el
>   cliente y el servidor.
>
> Los datos almacenados en localStorage persisten hasta que se eliminan
>   explícitamente. Los cambios realizados se guardan y están disponibles
>   para todas las visitas actuales y futuras del sitio.
>
> Funciona en la política del mismo origen. Por lo tanto, los datos
>   almacenados solo estarán disponibles en el mismo origen.

#### Ejemplo

```js
// seteo y almaceno en la variable miGato el valor Juan
window.localStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan');

// obtengo el valor de miGato
var gato = window.localStorage.getItem('miGato');

// lo muestro en el log
console.log(gato);

// elimino la variable miGato
window.localStorage.removeItem('miGato');

// elimino toda la data almacenada
window.localStorage.clear();
```

### `cookies`

> Podemos establecer el tiempo de caducidad de cada cookie.
>
> El límite de 4K es para toda la cookie, incluido el nombre, el valor,
>   la fecha de caducidad, etc. Para admitir la mayoría de los
>   navegadores, mantenga el nombre bajo 4000 bytes y el tamaño total de
>   la cookie bajo 4093 bytes.
>
> Los datos se envían al servidor para cada solicitud HTTP (HTML,
>   imágenes, JavaScript, CSS, etc.), lo que aumenta la cantidad de
>   tráfico entre el cliente y el servidor.

#### Ejemplo

```js
// función para setear cookies
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var expires = "";
  
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

// función para obtener cookies
function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

// función para borrar cookies
function eraseCookie(name) {   
  document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}

// uso

// nombre, valor, días para que expire
setCookie('miGato', 'Juan', 7);

var gato = getCookie('miGato');

console.log(gato);

// elimino la cookie
eraseCookie('miGato');
```

### `sessionStorage`

> Es similar al almacenamiento local.
>
> Los cambios solo están disponibles por ventana (o pestaña en
>   navegadores como Chrome y Firefox). Los cambios realizados se guardan
>   y están disponibles para la página actual, así como para futuras
>   visitas al sitio en la misma ventana. Una vez cerrada la ventana, se
>   borra el almacenamiento.
>
> Los datos solo están disponibles dentro de la ventana / pestaña en la
>   que se configuró. Los datos no son persistentes, es decir, se perderán
>   una vez que se cierre la ventana / pestaña. Como localStorage,
>   funciona en la política del mismo origen. Por lo tanto, los datos
>   almacenados solo estarán disponibles en el mismo origen.

#### Ejemplo

```js
// seteo y almaceno en la variable miGato el valor Juan
window.sessionStorage.setItem('miGato', 'Juan');

// obtengo el valor de miGato desde sessionStorage
var gato = window.sessionStorage.getItem('miGato');

// lo muestro en el log
console.log(gato);

// elimino la variable miGato
window.sessionStorage.removeItem('miGato');

// elimino toda la data almacenada
window.sessionStorage.clear();
```